# Font style in ref and autoref

Tags: fonts, cross-referencing, ref, autoref

I'd like to use both \autoref and \ref, so when enumerating references in the text I can get something like "Ecuaciones 1 y 2" (with *Ecuación 1* being a link inserted by \autoref and *2* a link inserted by \ref). The problem is that I need all the references in the text to be sans serif, but I can't get \autoref and \ref to use sans serif by default, and inserting \textsf or \sffamily in every case wouldn't be practical. With this MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-noindentfirst, es-nosectiondot]{babel}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\sffamily\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}
\usepackage[font={sf, footnotesize}]{caption}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Este texto es sólo para incluir las referencias a la \autoref{tab:prueba}, la \autoref{eq:ecuacion1} y la \ref{eq:ecuacion2}.

\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\caption{Prueba de tabla.}
\label{tab:prueba}
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
Columna 1 & Columna 2 & Resultados\\
1 & 1 & 2
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:ecuacion1}
1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:ecuacion2}
1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I get this:
[image]

which shows a terrible mess of mismatched fonts: *Tabla 0.0* is all serif, *Ecuación* is in serif, but *0.1* and *0.2* are sans serif.

I tried things like:

```
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\sffamily\thechapter.\arabic{table}}
```

but doing so ruins the formatting of the captions.

Is there any way of getting all cross references in sans serif? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cleveref` package does all the hard work for you:

```
\documentclass[twoside, 11pt,spanish]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-noindentfirst, es-nosectiondot]{babel}
%\renewcommand{\theequation}{\sffamily\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}
%\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}
\usepackage[font={sf, footnotesize}]{caption}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage[capitalise,nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}


\makeatletter
\def\@setcref{\sffamily\@@setcref{cref}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Este texto es sólo para incluir las referencias a la \cref{tab:prueba}, la \cref{eq:ecuacion1,eq:ecuacion2}.

\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\caption{Prueba de tabla.}
\label{tab:prueba}
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
Columna 1 & Columna 2 & Resultados\\
1 & 1 & 2
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:ecuacion1}
1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:ecuacion2}
1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! (and quick answer). It solved my problem.

Comment: @Pertrecho Glad to hear that your problem is solved!